# Return results from Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code in js with which I am trying to request something from api and then return the result or error, but in the other file when I try to log this I get "Undefined" value. What am i missing here?

```
import {baseAPI} from "../core/globals";
import axios from "axios/index";

export const getUserPosts = () => {
    return(
        axios({
            method : 'get',
            url: baseAPI+'post',
            headers:{
                Authorization : localStorage.getItem('token')
            }}
        ).then((result) => {
            return result.data
        }).catch((error) => {
            return error;
        })
    );
}
```

The other file looks like this

```
import { getUserPosts } from '../actions/userProfile';
import {baseAPI} from "../core/globals";

export default class Profile extends React.Component{

    state = {
        postResult : {}
    };
    componentDidMount(){
        let temp = getUserPosts();
        console.log(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: "but in the other file" — What other file? Show us a [mcve].

Comment: Odds are that `result.data` is simply `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you have is that `axios` returns a `Promise` and you are not waiting for your `Promise` to be resolved. Therefore the value returned from your `axios` method is `undefined` in your console log.

What you should use in your `componentDidMount` method is:

```
getUserPosts()
.then((temp) => {
  console.log(temp);
});
```

**Update:**
An alternative, if you're using Node v7.6.0 or greater is to take advantage of the `async` and `await` keywords to ask your code to wait for the promise to be resolved.

So you could also use:

```
componentDidMount () {
  let temp = await getUserPosts();
  console.log(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I was just expecting a result and didn't know that that function would behave that way. Thank you once again !

Comment: No problem. I have also updated my answer with another possible alternative way to do it.

Comment: this worked for me. I am using a different case where I am importing the module which has axios in it. And then I just use the .then on the imported module and it works

Answer (score 4):

`getUserPosts` returns a promise, so you need to make sure it is fulfilled before you do anything with the result.

**Example**

```
export default class Profile extends React.Component{
    state = {
        postResult : {}
    };
    componentDidMount(){
        getUserPosts().then(temp => {
            console.log(temp);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the idea , i have all my action separated and i just want to get a result or an error. While inspecting in the current file it works just fine, meaning that i get the array of object with the result. But when on the file which is imported it shows "Undefined"

Comment: @juxhinbleta If you `console.log` the `result.data` in `getUserPosts` you get the correct data, but if you try the code in my answer you get `undefined`?